# Не срабатывает join JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, join

Нужно сформировать строку с элементов массива, добавление в массив у меня происходит через ключ элемента, массив объявляется через фигурные скобки, в этом случае join не срабатывает. Подскажите, как решить проблему? Если сразу в массив добавить элементы - тогда выводит, а если так как мне нужно - нет.

```
var arr = {};

arr[1] = "Самолет";
arr[2] = "Машина";

console.log(arr.join(' '));
```

Comment: `{}` - это не массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы путаете массив с объектом

```js
var arr = [];

arr[1] = "Самолет";
arr[2] = "Машина";

console.log('arr - ' + arr.join(' '));

var obj = {};
obj.elem1 = "Самолет";
obj.elem2 = "Машина";

console.log('obj - ' + JSON.stringify(obj));
```